# The automation rule fired when an event executed leads to a wrong execution of the code

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api, python-jira

I am firing an event based on a transition called "Generate Features" executed as you can see below:
[image]

Also, based on an automation rule, I am executing some code. Here is the automation rule that I have:

[image]

The problem is that I am getting a message saying that the issue does not have an component which is wrong since the issue that I am testing my code on has 2 components as you can see below:
[image]
[image]
Here is the code to be executed as part of the automation rule:

```
package SuperFeature

import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import com.atlassian.jira.project.version.Version
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.project.component.ProjectComponent
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.project.component.ProjectComponentManager
import com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraAuthenticationContext
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.label.LabelManager

    
def log = Logger.getLogger('atlassian-jira.log')
List < String > componentList = new ArrayList < String > ()
List < ProjectComponent > finalComponentList = new ArrayList < ProjectComponent > ()
def projectNames = [ 'WF', 'BF', 'EF', 'YF', 'CLTF']

log.warn("=====MOUNA CAMELIA ISSUE:::: "+ issue +" ISSUE COMPONENTS "+issue.getComponents())
if (issue.getComponents().size() == 0) {
    issue.update {
         String text = "Issue does not have any components\n"

        setCustomFieldValue('Execution Summary', text )
    }
} else if (issue.getFixVersions().size() == 0) {
    issue.update {
        String text = "Issue does not have any fix versions\n"
        setCustomFieldValue('Execution Summary', text)
    }
} else {
    int componentSize = issue.getComponents().size()
   
    int generatedIssuesCounter= 0
     for (ProjectComponent component: issue.getComponents()) {
                      String componentName = component.getName()
                    def shortenedComponentName = componentName.substring(componentName.indexOf("-") + 1)
                    def projectName = componentName.substring(0, componentName.indexOf("-"))
                
                        

                        if(projectNames.contains(projectName)){

                        
                        
                        def newIssueproject = ComponentAccessor.projectManager.getProjectObjByKey(projectName)

                        //log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA found--"+found+"--NEW LIST SIZE: "+newList)
                        List < ProjectComponent > newList = new ArrayList < > (newIssueproject.getComponents());
                        def found = newList.any {
                            it.getName().equals(shortenedComponentName)
                        }
                        if (found) {
                            componentList.add(componentName+" ===> WILL BE GENERATED")
                            finalComponentList.add(component)
                            generatedIssuesCounter++
                        } else{
                            componentList.add(componentName+" ===> CANNOT BE GENERATED")

                        }
                        }
            
     }

     


    issue.update {
        String text = "The super feature " + issue + " will be split into " + generatedIssuesCounter + " features, one for each component:\n"
        
       text = text + componentList.join("\n")    ;
         // Partition a list into list of lists size 3
       

        setCustomFieldValue('Execution Summary', text)
    }
}
```